# Convert String to valid HTML

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a scenario, I have to load a url on `UIWebView` and when user go to specific url, I have to read all `HTML` of webpage and pass that `HTML` to my server, I already try to use

`self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document)")`

and

`self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.documentElement.outerHTML")`

With this I get `HTML` but it contains whitespaces and extra characters which make `HTML` invalid.

**Now my question is:**

How can I get valid `HTML` from webpage without extra whitespaces which was already loaded on `UIWebView`?

Comment: your question is not about the fact of how to convert valid html to a string, but rather `Why does html drawn from a different page become invalid` @MuhammadAhmedBaig

Comment: i have a webpage and i want to access it's all html, but in swift string it add some whitespaces and extra characters, which makes html invalid